# coxph in R, beta affected by value of factor?

Tags: r, interaction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm running a coxph right now. My setup: I have a reference (no treatment), and then three different treatments (A, B, and C). I also have the interactions of A, B, and C, (e.g. samples treated with both treatment A and B, or A and C, etc...). I created dummy variables for these treatments coded as 1 or 2 (1 = received treatment, 2 = did not receive treatment). I use `as.factor()` to load these variables.

```
example:
A<-as.factor(Data$A)
```

I can run this as follows, and get a result showing that receiving treatment B (aka B = 1) is beneficial to Lifespan (coef is positive). All three are significant in some way:

```
> coxph1<-coxph(Surv(Lifespan,Status)~A+B+C
> summary(coxph1)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Life, Status) ~ A + B + C, data = FlyData, 
    method = "efron")

  n= 162, number of events= 140 

     coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
A -0.3486    0.7057   0.1761 -1.980 0.047753 *  
B  0.5911    1.8059   0.1787  3.307 0.000944 ***
C -0.6956    0.4988   0.1815 -3.832 0.000127 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
A    0.7057     1.4170    0.4997    0.9966
B    1.8059     0.5537    1.2722    2.5635
C    0.4988     2.0050    0.3494    0.7119

Concordance= 0.822  (se = 0.095 )
Rsquare= 0.227   (max possible= 1 )
Likelihood ratio test= 41.75  on 3 df,   p=5e-09
Wald test            = 41.35  on 3 df,   p=6e-09
Score (logrank) test = 43.6  on 3 df,   p=2e-09
```

But when I run a coxph with interaction terms, where I want to know if A:B or A:C etc... have some interaction different from just A or B, I get the following:

```
> int.coxph <- coxph(Surv(Life, Status)~A*B*C, data=FlyData, method='efron')
```

***Warning message:
    In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
      Loglik converged before variable  1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ; beta may be infinite.***

```
> summary(int.coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Life, Status) ~ A * B * C, data = FlyData, 
    method = "efron")

  n= 162, number of events= 140 

            coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
A      3.987e+01  2.066e+17  4.945e+03  0.008    0.994
B      1.856e+01  1.148e+08  2.472e+03  0.008    0.994
C      3.799e+01  3.144e+16  4.945e+03  0.008    0.994
A:B   -1.964e+01  2.967e-09  2.472e+03 -0.008    0.994
A:C   -3.954e+01  6.737e-18  4.945e+03 -0.008    0.994
B:C   -1.874e+01  7.241e-09  2.472e+03 -0.008    0.994
A:B:C  1.962e+01  3.318e+08  2.472e+03  0.008    0.994

      exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
A     2.066e+17  4.841e-18         0       Inf
B     1.148e+08  8.714e-09         0       Inf
C     3.144e+16  3.180e-17         0       Inf
A:B   2.967e-09  3.370e+08         0       Inf
A:C   6.737e-18  1.484e+17         0       Inf
B:C   7.241e-09  1.381e+08         0       Inf
A:B:C 3.318e+08  3.014e-09         0       Inf

Concordance= 0.869  (se = 0.095 )
Rsquare= 0.51   (max possible= 1 )
Likelihood ratio test= 115.6  on 7 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 9.24  on 7 df,   p=0.2
Score (logrank) test = 73.69  on 7 df,   p=3e-13
```

So... this is similar to some other questions... but why does beta approach infinite? The added twist I have for this question is that if I recode the variables as 0 or 1 (instead of 1 and 2), then I can change the output in the interaction coxph(). This recoding for the coxph:

```
coxph2<-coxph(Surv(Lifespan, Status)~A2+B2+C2))
summary(coxph2)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Life, Status) ~ A2 + B2 + C2, data = FlyData, 
    method = "efron")

  n= 162, number of events= 140 

      coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
A2  0.3486    1.4170   0.1761  1.980 0.047753 *  
B2 -0.5911    0.5537   0.1787 -3.307 0.000944 ***
C2  0.6956    2.0050   0.1815  3.832 0.000127 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

   exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
A2    1.4170     0.7057    1.0035     2.001
B2    0.5537     1.8059    0.3901     0.786
C2    2.0050     0.4988    1.4048     2.862

Concordance= 0.822  (se = 0.095 )
Rsquare= 0.227   (max possible= 1 )
Likelihood ratio test= 41.75  on 3 df,   p=5e-09
Wald test            = 41.35  on 3 df,   p=6e-09
Score (logrank) test = 43.6  on 3 df,   p=2e-09
```

is just the inverse, but the interaction coxph is different...

```
> full.coxph <- coxph(Surv(Life, Status)~A2*B2*C2, data=FlyData, method='efron')
Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Loglik converged before variable  2,4,6,7 ; beta may be infinite. 
> summary(full.coxph)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Life, Status) ~ A2 * B2 * C2, data = FlyData, 
    method = "efron")

  n= 162, number of events= 140 

               coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
A2       -7.067e-15  1.000e+00  3.204e-01  0.000    1.000
B2       -2.028e+01  1.558e-09  2.472e+03 -0.008    0.993
C2        9.821e-02  1.103e+00  3.204e-01  0.307    0.759
A2:B2     1.960e+01  3.266e+08  2.472e+03  0.008    0.994
A2:C2    -2.991e-01  7.415e-01  4.475e-01 -0.668    0.504
B2:C2     2.050e+01  7.970e+08  2.472e+03  0.008    0.993
A2:B2:C2 -1.962e+01  3.014e-09  2.472e+03 -0.008    0.994

         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
A2       1.000e+00  1.000e+00    0.5337     1.874
B2       1.558e-09  6.417e+08    0.0000       Inf
C2       1.103e+00  9.065e-01    0.5888     2.067
A2:B2    3.266e+08  3.062e-09    0.0000       Inf
A2:C2    7.415e-01  1.349e+00    0.3085     1.782
B2:C2    7.970e+08  1.255e-09    0.0000       Inf
A2:B2:C2 3.014e-09  3.318e+08    0.0000       Inf

Concordance= 0.869  (se = 0.095 )
Rsquare= 0.51   (max possible= 1 )
Likelihood ratio test= 115.6  on 7 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 9.24  on 7 df,   p=0.2
Score (logrank) test = 73.69  on 7 df,   p=3e-13
```

Why should changing the numerical value of a categorical variable matter? :S What am I missing here... Re-trying this with non-numeric variables ("no" and "yes") gives the same result as using 0 and 1. e.g. upper .95 for A is "1.874", for B is "inf". Similarly, `coxph(Surv()~A+B+C)` gives a negative coef for B, just like the above.

Comment: Can you show the cross table of A, B and C?

Comment: It's 163 rows long. Is there a good way to do this?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zb7sxra40virai0/David_FemaleManis-example.R?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnxcln78a6motre/David_FemaleManis-example.xlsx?dl=0

For now I've uploaded the data and my (terribly written) code to dropbox. The excel file has the A, B, and C dummy variables re-coded in three different ways.

Thanks for the interest :)

Comment: the cross table of three dummy variables should be 3x3

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The dummy variables are indicating whether a sample was given treatment A, B, and/or C. So the length of the column is the number of rows?

Comment: Hmm... is there a better way to approach or organize this kind of data?

Admittedly, I am not a statistician, so am I correct in thinking that a "degenerate hat matrix" means the observed response values are almost infinitely different from the predicted values? Thus why the confidence interval approaches infinity? Would this be because I'm entering A, B, and C (dichotomous outcomes) as covariates?

Any idea why the fit would change if I use 0 and 1 to code this vs. 1 and 2?

Comment: It's quite possibly just a numerical issue (combined with possibly not enough data points and events in each of the factor levels to support a complex model.  You haven't shown us the actual data  but the output doesn't make me think these factors were improperly constructed. BTW how many events do you have and how are they distributed in the groups? You should have events in each factor and interaction  level

Comment: I have 140 total events out of 162 samples. Admittedly this is just sample data I'm working with, generated from a single experiment with about 20 replicates per treatment (i.e. 20 A, 20 B, 20 C, 20 A:B, etc...). Ideally, B should be very strongly beneficial for survival because zero B flies died. There's maybe an interaction between A and B, but that's one of the things I'm curious to see. I linked the data in the comments above via dropbox. It could just be a sample size thing. I'll try increasing the sample size by just copying to see how that affects things tomorrow. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably (almost certainly in fact) have a nearly degenerate "hat matrix" which is what is formed from the model matrix with that interaction. You have all the second order interactions as well as 
 the third order interactions. Depending on the number of levels in the factors the numbers of terms required to fully populate the model matrix might be very large. What I would try next is a model with slightly fewer terms in the model. You can use R's formula interface to remove the third order terms and only leave the first and second terms in one of two ways:

```
int.coxph <- coxph(Surv(Life, Status)~( A+B+C)^2, data=FlyData, method='efron')
```

Or:

```
int.coxph <- coxph(Surv(Life, Status)~ A*B*C - A:B:C, data=FlyData, method='efron')
```

It's not certain you will get satisfaction this way. It's possible that you don't have sufficient data to avoid the degeneracy in constructing the XX^t matrix but if your results do not  blow up in as obvious a manner as is seen above, then perhaps the results will be meaningful. Another safer method would be to look first at the reduced model and then add back in specific interactions:

```
 int.coxph.base <- coxph(Surv(Life, Status)~A+B+C,      data=FlyData, method='efron')
int.coxph.intAB <- coxph(Surv(Life, Status)~A+B+C +A:B, data=FlyData, method='efron')
```

This second option would have the added advantage of allowing you to easily construct tests based on the change in log-likelihood rather than depending on the less reliable Wald-type tests that you see in the default printouts for `print.coxph` or `summary.coxph`.

Comment: Thanks again for the input. Removing the third-order terms helps avoid approaching infinity, and removing all interaction terms and adding them back also yields an output that avoids infinity. Unfortunately, how the interaction terms contribute to the model seems totally bizarre... even if A and C are clearly harmful and B is clearly helpful, it outputs a model claiming A, B, and C all contribute positively to survival. 

I increased the sample size by 8x to try and avoid violating intrinsic assumptions re: the # of events etc... not that I fully understand the background statistics...

Comment: Reading implications off the coefficients can be (make that almost always is...) misleading with interaction models. Better practice is to use the predict function and put in your desired contrast in the `newdata`.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized one of the issues causing my problem: there simply wasn't enough resolution in my survival data. I couldn't differentiate the effects of the interaction terms. If I design my data to yield an answer, then I can get reasonable model loading outputs and interaction terms that make sense. At the end of the day, I plan to use a combined approach of all three model types. i.e.:

```
coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~A+B+C, data=data) #Additive effects
coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~Treatment, data=data) #Base treatment effects
coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~A+B+A:B, data=data) #Test interactions of interest
```

A basic understanding of the additive effects gives you a sense of how the covariates globally contribute to survival. Analyzing the treatment effects (i.e. the fundamental variable of interest) gives you a sense of whether the groups differ, and from that you can infer patterns using the additive effects and the variables of interest.

Using 42-'s approach of investigating only terms of interest is also highly useful in analyzing the data. No matter how I manipulate the data, even data I've designed to be informative has trouble when you include all interaction terms in a tripartite model. But using only interactions of interest can increase understanding.

I suppose this sort of post-hoc analysis requires independent validation from a second experiment focusing on the terms of interest.